# Make image resize when too large, but not larger than the image itself with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make an image resize in a box on my website when it exceeds the width of the box. You could do this by simply making it 100% of the box's width. However, you would get images that are sized up then, which looks ugly. So what I want is that the image only is 100% when it is larger than the surrounding box, and below that I want it to be its original dimensions. Can this be solved with CSS? I know this can be solved with javascript too, but I'd rather do it with CSS.

Comment: `img { max-width:100%; }`

Comment: This is currently not possible using css only you will nee JS.

Comment: Using @Marcelo's comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lowethca/z0725q1n/

Comment: Also here XD http://jsfiddle.net/dd9sohpm/

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px; /*whatever the actual width of your picture is*/
}
```

Comment: @dwreck08: As I wrote, the max-width has to be set to whatever the width of the picture is. This of course is limited if that picture is dynamic, but it works absolutely fine with static images like logos.